# array join partitioned by column in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am using spark sql. Let's say I have a table like this

```
ID,Grade
1,A
2,B
1,A
2,C
```

I want to make arrays that contain all the grades for each id. But i don't want to collapse the table with a group by. I am trying to maitain all the IDs. My desired output is the following:

```
ID,Grade
1,[A, A]
1,[A,A]
2,[B,C]
2,[B,C]
```

My query is the following

```
SELECT array_join(collect_list(GRADE), ",") AS GRADES
        OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
FROM table
```

However i get an error like this:

```
AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'ID' is not an aggregate function.
```

Any idea how to fix my query?  Thank you

Comment: I don't know all the ins and outs of spark, but if you can nest queries you can collapse with the Group By in inner query, then in outer query join it back to the original table.

Comment: Yeah i thought of doing it  this way, but i wonder why the partition is not working

Answer (score 0):

In your query, `collect_list` is the aggregate function, so you if you want to use a window you need to apply it directly on `collect_list`:

```sql
SELECT id,
       array_join(collect_list(GRADE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) , ",") AS GRADES 
FROM table
```